# Export signed application package with command line

Tags: android

Until now i make an apk file in the normal way:
Andoid tools -> Export signed application package...

and there i give the key and the alias and than it make my apk file that i post in the market.

now i want to do the same thing with a terminal

I try to use the ant with : `ant release` command but it give me an unsigned application package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add lines of the following form to your build.properties file (SDK pre 14) 
or ant.properties file (SDK 14 and beyond)

Then the if you call 'ant release' the signing with the correct passwords will 
be automatically done for you

(Assuming your release keystore is at : c:/users/you/my-release-key.keystore
and your release key's alias is : your_release_alias)

```
key.store=c:/users/you/my-release-key.keystore
key.alias=your_release_alias
key.store.password=YourKeystorePassword
key.alias.password=YourKeyaliasPassword
```

.

Comment: but i don't have this files in my project

Comment: It might be an idea for you to read the section on 'managing projects from the command line' in the docs. It tells you how to make a sample project which will make these files and the build.xml which ant needs, see :                          http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html